# @Provider AND Registration in Application(ResourceConfig) requirement for custom MessageBodyWriter/Reader?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, provider

Is there a requirement that a custom MessageBodyWriter and MessageBodyReader must not only be annotated by *@Provider* annotation AND also be included in the *Application* configuration through *Application* or *ResourceConfig*. If yes, why?

My train of thought was that, if classes are annotated with *@Provider* then the JAX-RS runtime by default loads such classes as it's runtime component. Declaring the same class inside the *Application* makes is a redundant exercise. It appears my train of thought is wrong, but I am looking for some kind of explanation on how and why this has been designed this way(ie both annotation and Application configuration).

I can understand that some form of Application configuration would be required on the Jersey Client side, but am not very confident about that either.

For instance, the JavaMarshaller class below has been annotated with @Provider

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Produces("application/example-java")
@Consumes("application/example-java")
public class JavaMarshaller implements MessageBodyReader, MessageBodyWriter {
.......
```

Now in the Application class is it required to do as below?

```
@ApplicationPath("services")
public class ShoppingApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public ShoppingApplication() {
        classes.add(JavaMarshaller.class);
    }

.........
```

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: Deploying it on Tomcat 8.0 with all Jersey jars in WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the registration of classes dynamically is a feature of application servers. Since your'e deploying to tomcat, Jersey will likely expect that you're listing your providers and resources in your `Application` class.

If you were deploying to a full app server, like WildFly or GlassFish, you wouldn't need to do this.